# Setting Content type with Default Request Headers

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, httpcontent

When using `HttpClient`, I have read examples (such as [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)) that uses `DefaultRequestHeaders` to set the content type (such as "application/json") of a Post request.

I tried to do something like this, but it failed. The `API` I am sending requests complained that it was sent an "unsupported type" (which it says when the content type is not set to `json`).

After that I added one line and I solved the issue (you can see the line in the code below commented).

My question is why is this line necessary? And if I include this line (that is setting the content type of the *content*) doesn't that make the "default request header" setting unnecessary. What is this "default request header" doing if anything?

(I actually tried and commented the lines related to `DefaultRequestHeaders` and it worked without problem. So what is `DefaultRequestHeaders` good for?)

**My code is :**

```
// Get the bytes for the request, should be pre-escaped
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonEmployeeData);

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("the address here");
//  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
       new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("customHeader", "blahblahblah");

ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);  //Make a new instance of HttpContent (an abstract class that can't be instantiated)

//THIS is the solution
//byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");  //If I UNCOMMENT THIS, IT WORKS!!

try
   {
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("staff", byteContent);
  Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
  {
 Console.WriteLine("Something happened, oopps!" + ex.Message);
  }
Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
Console.ReadLine();
```

`client` is a `HttpClient` by the way.

Comment: I am not sure as to why the earlier isn't working for you, but did you try using fiddler to notice any difference between the two? If you haven't yet, I would highly recommend exploring fiddler by telerik - https://www.telerik.com/fiddler. You could basically inspect the request and response of request, and it has great features like filtering requests based on domain, header inspections etc.

Answer (score 2):

The API you called needs the request content is **application/json** format, so you have to specify this format in your content. That's why that line of code is the one you need:

```
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
```

About the line:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
       new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
```

This is request **Accept** header, it means the content type of response which you expect the server return to you. (You can expect server returns another content type like text/plain,...). Hope this helps!